# Why is this the output of this exception stack?

Tags: c++, exception

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Error {
    string msg;
public:
    Error(string s) : msg(s) {} string get_msg()
    {
        return msg;
    }
};

void goodbye() {
    cout << "goodbye!\n";
    throw Error("goodbye error");
    cout << "goodbye() returns\n";
}

void hello()
{
    cout << "hello world!\n";
    try
    {
        goodbye();
    }
    catch (Error e)
    {
        throw Error("hello error");
    }
    cout << "hello() returns\n";
}

int main() {
    try {
    hello();
    cout << "done\n";
    }
    catch (Error e)
    {
        cout << e.get_msg() << endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Unknown error"
        << endl;
    }
    cout << "main() returns\n";
    return 0;
}
```

this is the output:

```
hello world!
goodbye!
hello error
main() returns
```

I know that the main goes into the hello function, but what I don't understand is the order in which the stack is getting executed and why the throw error "hello error" line is being executed.

Comment: Then step through the code line by line with a debugger.

Comment: If you dont understand that, then that means you're working with too many statements. I'd suggest you to add one stuff at a time, then see how things get executed, and in what order. Add few more `cout` to track the path (especially in the constructor of `Error`).

Answer (score 0):

- function `hello` is executed
- `"hello world!"` is outputted
- function `goodbye` is executed
- `"goodbye!"` is outputted
- `Error("goodbye error");` is thrown
- As no exception handler present in `goodbye`, it quits
- `Error("goodbye error");` is catched in `hello`
- `Error("hello error");` is thrown
- As no further exception handler present in `hello`, it quits
- `Error("hello error");` is catched in main
- Error message (`hello error`) is output
- rest of main is executed
- `"main() returns"` is outputted